# Text becomes transparent at top

Tags: css, background-image

I want to reach an effect like in the example, but use opacity instead blur. Imagine like text becomes transparent at top when you scrolling content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(black, black, transparent);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="content"><div>
 
Nam lacus libero, interdum euismod dui quis, sodales aliquam massa. Vivamus eget faucibus est, at tincidunt metus. Nulla eleifend aliquet purus. Nunc semper, lectus ut interdum pellentesque, velit ante feugiat arcu, non accumsan ex nulla a libero. Fusce vitae lectus iaculis, accumsan urna in, egestas mauris. Integer nec mi facilisis, fringilla eros sed, imperdiet purus. Ut in velit mi. Vivamus leo arcu, consectetur sed tellus commodo, dictum feugiat ex. Aliquam id arcu rutrum, euismod ligula at, vestibulum augue. Phasellus et nibh a nulla tempor sagittis. Nulla placerat magna quis tincidunt malesuada. Donec eleifend mollis eros, id vulputate est tempus a. Curabitur rutrum imperdiet turpis a accumsan. Ut malesuada varius mi, id varius purus malesuada at.
Nam lacus libero, interdum euismod dui quis, sodales aliquam massa. Vivamus eget faucibus est, at tincidunt metus. Nulla eleifend aliquet purus. Nunc semper, lectus ut interdum pellentesque, velit ante feugiat arcu, non accumsan ex nulla a libero. Fusce vitae lectus iaculis, accumsan urna in, egestas mauris. Integer nec mi facilisis, fringilla eros sed, imperdiet purus. Ut in velit mi. Vivamus leo arcu, consectetur sed tellus commodo, dictum feugiat ex. Aliquam id arcu rutrum, euismod ligula at, vestibulum augue. Phasellus et nibh a nulla tempor sagittis. Nulla placerat magna quis tincidunt malesuada. Donec eleifend mollis eros, id vulputate est tempus a. Curabitur rutrum imperdiet turpis a accumsan. Ut malesuada varius mi, id varius purus malesuada at.


</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: because you use `backdrop-filter: blur(8px);`

Comment: and I suppose you don't want to use a red (same as background) overlay on the top to simulate this?

Comment: BTW, it's `::before`, not `:before` - the single-colon syntax only works due to back-compat.

Comment: Yes, background can be any color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I've used a `mask-image` property for the parent container, and now I can change bg to any color and image

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #000 50%, transparent);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #000 50%, transparent);
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="content"><div>
 
Nam lacus libero, interdum euismod dui quis, sodales aliquam massa. Vivamus eget faucibus est, at tincidunt metus. Nulla eleifend aliquet purus. Nunc semper, lectus ut interdum pellentesque, velit ante feugiat arcu, non accumsan ex nulla a libero. Fusce vitae lectus iaculis, accumsan urna in, egestas mauris. Integer nec mi facilisis, fringilla eros sed, imperdiet purus. Ut in velit mi. Vivamus leo arcu, consectetur sed tellus commodo, dictum feugiat ex. Aliquam id arcu rutrum, euismod ligula at, vestibulum augue. Phasellus et nibh a nulla tempor sagittis. Nulla placerat magna quis tincidunt malesuada. Donec eleifend mollis eros, id vulputate est tempus a. Curabitur rutrum imperdiet turpis a accumsan. Ut malesuada varius mi, id varius purus malesuada at.
Nam lacus libero, interdum euismod dui quis, sodales aliquam massa. Vivamus eget faucibus est, at tincidunt metus. Nulla eleifend aliquet purus. Nunc semper, lectus ut interdum pellentesque, velit ante feugiat arcu, non accumsan ex nulla a libero. Fusce vitae lectus iaculis, accumsan urna in, egestas mauris. Integer nec mi facilisis, fringilla eros sed, imperdiet purus. Ut in velit mi. Vivamus leo arcu, consectetur sed tellus commodo, dictum feugiat ex. Aliquam id arcu rutrum, euismod ligula at, vestibulum augue. Phasellus et nibh a nulla tempor sagittis. Nulla placerat magna quis tincidunt malesuada. Donec eleifend mollis eros, id vulputate est tempus a. Curabitur rutrum imperdiet turpis a accumsan. Ut malesuada varius mi, id varius purus malesuada at.


</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a linear gradient as `background`, starting at your background color and ending transparent:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(red, transparent);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="content"><div>
 
Nam lacus libero, interdum euismod dui quis, sodales aliquam massa. Vivamus eget faucibus est, at tincidunt metus. Nulla eleifend aliquet purus. Nunc semper, lectus ut interdum pellentesque, velit ante feugiat arcu, non accumsan ex nulla a libero. Fusce vitae lectus iaculis, accumsan urna in, egestas mauris. Integer nec mi facilisis, fringilla eros sed, imperdiet purus. Ut in velit mi. Vivamus leo arcu, consectetur sed tellus commodo, dictum feugiat ex. Aliquam id arcu rutrum, euismod ligula at, vestibulum augue. Phasellus et nibh a nulla tempor sagittis. Nulla placerat magna quis tincidunt malesuada. Donec eleifend mollis eros, id vulputate est tempus a. Curabitur rutrum imperdiet turpis a accumsan. Ut malesuada varius mi, id varius purus malesuada at.
Nam lacus libero, interdum euismod dui quis, sodales aliquam massa. Vivamus eget faucibus est, at tincidunt metus. Nulla eleifend aliquet purus. Nunc semper, lectus ut interdum pellentesque, velit ante feugiat arcu, non accumsan ex nulla a libero. Fusce vitae lectus iaculis, accumsan urna in, egestas mauris. Integer nec mi facilisis, fringilla eros sed, imperdiet purus. Ut in velit mi. Vivamus leo arcu, consectetur sed tellus commodo, dictum feugiat ex. Aliquam id arcu rutrum, euismod ligula at, vestibulum augue. Phasellus et nibh a nulla tempor sagittis. Nulla placerat magna quis tincidunt malesuada. Donec eleifend mollis eros, id vulputate est tempus a. Curabitur rutrum imperdiet turpis a accumsan. Ut malesuada varius mi, id varius purus malesuada at.


</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: No, background can have any color or image. Here if I change wrapper bg color to image it won't work

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS liner-gradient. Please try this:

```
.content:after {
   ...other properties...
   background:(180deg, black(or any color you want), rgba(0,0,0,0))
}
```

Comment: No, background can have any color or image. Here if I change wrapper bg color to image it won't work